# Collection Cell Content Size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I added a view as parent red view in CollectionViewCell and the next blue subview at the center of the parent view. It works correctly and the sub view goes at the center of the parent view before collection cell size is not changed. But, The cell size is changed by conforming the method from UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol and the view is not centered of the cell correctly. How I can solve this issue ?

```
class ItemCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {  
   var parentView: UIView!
   var circularView: UIView!    
   var itemImage: UIImageView!    
   var itemName: UILabel!   
   override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)       
     //  self.updateView()
   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
      self.updateView()
   }

   func updateView(){
      self.clipsToBounds = true
      self.parentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 
         self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height))

      self.parentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
      self.circularView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 
        self.parentView.frame.size.width / 4 , height: 
          self.parentView.frame.size.width / 4 ))
      self.circularView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
      self.addSubview(parentView)
      self.parentView.addSubview(self.circularView)
      self.circularView.center = self.parentView.center
  }
}
```

[image: Before conform protocol and size is not changed for indexPath[![View is not centered correctly][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxw9C.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RULza.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
self.circularView.center = CGPoint(x: self. parentView.bounds.midX, y: self. parentView.bounds.midY)
self.parentView.addSubview(self.circularView)
self.addSubview(parentView)
```

Comment: Try by calling updateView from awakeFromNib Method. Why you dont go with custom nib.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
self.circularView.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.parentView.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.parentView.bounds))
```

Why this should work? Try checking values of `self.parentView.center` for each cell, they might not be what you want them to be, because [center property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622627-center) gives values with respect to parent view coordinate system.

Comment: Check if your parentview is bigger (cropped) than your Cell content view. It basically falls outside your cell and so you are unable to see that circularView is indeed in the center. XCode has this tool called Debug View Hierarchy, accessible via Debug->View Debugging.

Comment: Found it bro. It is bigger than the cell size and croped. It is at the center. How can I fit it in the cell ?

Comment: Consider adding parentview to self.contentView instead of self. Also put breakpoint to see what is self.frame.size value is while initializing parentview. Try replacing it with self.contentView.frame.size.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from updateView()

```
self.circularView.center = self.parentView.center
```

Please add it to the following method:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.circularView.center = self.parentView.center
}
```

e.g.

```
class ItemCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
        var parentView: UIView!
        var circularView: UIView!
        var itemImage: UIImageView!
        var itemName: UILabel!
        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            //  self.updateView()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            self.updateView()
        }

        func updateView(){
            self.clipsToBounds = true
            self.parentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width:
                self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height))

            self.parentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            self.circularView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:
                self.parentView.frame.size.width / 4 , height:
                self.parentView.frame.size.width / 4 ))
            self.circularView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            self.addSubview(parentView)
            self.parentView.addSubview(self.circularView)
        }

        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            self.circularView.center = self.parentView.center
        }
    }
```

Comment: Need to call layoutSubviews() from collection view protocol CollectionCell inflate method ?